# Raster Calculator Syntax - ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-calculator

I'm trying to reclassify a raster based upon two criteria 1. Raster cell on "CBH" is less than or equal to 2 AND "footprint" is not null. Then output raster reclassifies any cell inside this criteria to '3'.

Not sure of input and output raster syntax. What I have so far.

("us_110cbh_1" <= 2)  &  ~IsNull("foot_buff_100").

I used a syntax found here a few weeks ago that included 'inras' and 'outras', but of course I didn't save it and can't find it again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`("CBH" <= 2) & ~IsNull("footprint")` looks fine, assuming they are your raster layer names.

For your reference have a read of [Map Algebra](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00p600000002000000), input output syntax is explained a little [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_rules_for_Map_Algebra/00p600000006000000/).

To actually use this you will need to do a [CON](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000005000000.htm):

```
Con(("CBH" <= 2) & ~IsNull("footprint"),True_value,False_value)
```

Your True_value is 3, false value is optional.

Comment: They are indeed my raster layer names. I'm not sure how to reclassify the resulting cells.

Comment: The output of an AND operation would be a grid of ones and zeros. I think you need to wrap this logic up in a [CON](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000005000000.htm) tool.

Comment: 100% correct @Hornbydd, you would need a con or similar to actually do something with this logic equation.

Comment: I have figured out how to use the CON tool, except the part where I can't find is how to set the False_value to whatever it already is .... that is do nothing.

Comment: supply the input raster. The true is *true constant or raster* and false is *false constant or raster*

Comment: I went with:

OutRas = Con(("CBH" <= 2) & ~IsNull("footprint"),3,"CBH")

And it seemed to work.  Thanks for all your help, everyone.